# Apostrophes (') is not recognised in regular expression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I want a regular expression for first name that can contain

1)Alphabets
2)Spaces
3)Apostrophes

Exp:  Raja, Raja reddy, Raja's,

I used this `^([a-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[a-z]+[']?)+$` but it is failing to recognise Apostrophes (').

```
- (BOOL)validateFirstNameOrLastNameOrCity:(NSString *) inputCanditate {
    NSString *firstNameRegex =  @"^([a-z]+[,.]?[ ]?|[a-z]+[']?)+$";
    NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@",firstNameRegex];
    return [firstNamePredicate evaluateWithObject:inputCanditate];
}
```

Comment: I don't know why people always insist on validating names, but any way, just do `^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z,.' -]+$`

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: it is not working for ('). it fails for O'Lary name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I recommand ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ']* ?

```
// The NSRegularExpression class is currently only available in the Foundation framework of iOS 4
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[A-Z][a-zA-Z ']*" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:searchText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
return numberOfMatches > 1;
```

^[A-Z] : Force start with a capital letter from A to Z

[a-zA-Z ']* : followed by any number of charactere that an be 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', space or simple quote

Comment: Thanks for response . I combined your answers with the following. comment.

Comment: /*In iOS 11 Apple introduced "Smart Punctuation", which automatically slants certain punctuation marks based on content.
     iOS 10: "double quotes", 'single quotes'
     iOS 11 (with Smart Punctuation on): “double quotes”, ‘single quotes’
     */
    
    Solution is :  NSString *firstNameRegex =  @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z- '‘’]*";

Comment: @MuraliMohan Thanks for `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z- '‘’]`. It really helped me a lot. Was stucked this with past 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a pattern like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iaEWUL/1): `^[a-zA-Z ']+$`

However, this is pretty bad. What about umlauts, accents, and a whole lot other letters that are not part of the ASCII alphabet?

A better solution would be to allow any kind of letter from any language.
To do so you can use the Unicode "letter" category `\p{L}`, e.g. `^[\p{L}]+$`.
.. or you could just drop that rule all together - as reasonably suggested.